Winforms как исправить логику в коде для коректно подсчета при повторном нажатии на = выдает не верный результат
как сделать так чтоб после повторного нажатия на равно при сложении чисел  повторного нажатия выдало при сложение 5+5 = 10 + 5 = 15,  подскажтие где не правильно реализована логика и как это можно исправь?
Метод выбора оператора:
public void math_action(char action)
     {
     if (this.user_action == ' ' || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.result_lab.Text))
     {
         return;
     }

     this.second_num = Convert.ToDouble(this.result_lab.Text);

     if (this.dec && !lastButtonWasOperation)
     {
         Score(); // Вызываем функцию Score для выполнения предыдущей операции
         this.result_lab2.Text = Convert.ToString(this.first_num);
     }
     else
     {
         this.first_num = Convert.ToDouble(this.result_lab.Text);
         this.result_lab2.Text = Convert.ToString(this.first_num);
     }

     this.user_action = action;

     switch (action)
     {
         case '+': this.result_lab2.Text += " + "; break;
         case '-': this.result_lab2.Text += " - "; break;
         case '*': this.result_lab2.Text += " * "; break;
         case '/': this.result_lab2.Text += " / "; break;
         case '%': this.result_lab2.Text += " % "; break;
     }

     this.again = true;
     this.dec = true;
     lastButtonWasOperation = true;
 }

Метод сложения отвечает за результат
public void Score()
 {
     if (this.user_action == ' ' || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.result_lab.Text))
     {
         return;
     }

     double second = Convert.ToDouble(this.result_lab.Text);
     double res = 0;
     this.result_lab2.Text += Convert.ToString(second) + "=";

     switch (this.user_action)
     {
         case '+': res = this.first_num + second; break;
         case '-': res = this.first_num - second; break;
         case '*': res = this.first_num * second; break;
         case '%': res = this.first_num * (second / 100); break; // Изменено здесь
         case '/':
             if (second != 0)
             {
                 res = this.first_num / second;
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(this, "Действие запрещено, на 0 делить нельзя!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 this.result_lab2.Text = "";
             }
             break;
     }
     
     this.first_num = res; // Сохраняем результат как первое число для следующей операции
     
     this.result_lab.Text = Convert.ToString(res);
    private void button_sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (user_action == ' ')
    {
        return;
    }
    this.dec = false;
    this.again = true;
    
    Score();

}

Дополнение - Решил следующим способом, добавив флаг записи второго числа в отдельную переменную и переписал логику в методе Score.

Не пишите дополнение к аопросу в комментариях, вместо этого можете отредактировать сам вопрос.

Понял, спасибо.

Решил, добавив флаг для проверки и переписал логику в методе Score.

Что именно вы сделали? Непонятно.

Так понятнее модератор?

Если бы на ваш вопрос я дал ответ "перепишите логику в методе Score", вы бы сразу же моментально приняли ответ и вопрос бы решился? Сомневаюсь. Ответ должен содержать исчерпывающую информацию для решения вопроса.

Ну я для себя понял в чем дело, я же не смотрел что мне написали я заранее обозначил что решил.

Ответы как и вопросы здесь вы оставляете не только для себя, но и для будущих посетителей, которые будут искать решение такой же или схожей проблемы.

понял в следующий раз буду внимателен
